# Error in Copying access DB from one folder to another using excel VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel

Hey I am not able to copy an access DB from one folder to another using excel vba . I am not getting any error ... But still no file is getting copied...Instead i am getting something called '873ED000' with 0 bytes.   What could be the reason?.  Please help me out.
Also is this the best method to copy ?? My tool needs to be faster and the Database is huge.

```
FileCopy "E:\Test Folder\Feature_Planning_Data.accdb", "" & ThisWorkbook.Path &       "Feature_Planning_Data.accdb
```

Comment: If the file is huge, are you sure you have Compacted & Repaired recently?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (I am assuming that the Excel File from where you are running the code is saved)

```
FileCopy "E:\Test Folder\Feature_Planning_Data.accdb", _
ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Feature_Planning_Data.accdb"
```